# How to update Salesforce API version in Mule

Tags: salesforce, mule, anypoint-studio

I am seeing this warning message and wanted to know how to update so I am using v38 or higher as recommended?

```
WARN  2016-12-13 12:16:55,221 [[test].test-order-system-httpListenerConfig.worker.01] org.mule.modules.salesforce.config.AbstractConfig: API version 37.0 is lower than the recommended 38.0 version
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have correct dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
              <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
              <artifactId>mule-module-sfdc</artifactId>
              <version>8.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and url has correct ver

.......salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/38.0